# What is the process for converting a large .SID file to an ArcGIS Online TIle Layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, mrsid

I have a large aerial imagery .sid file of measuring 4.5gb. This .sid file needs to be added to a AGOL web application as a base layer.

What is the process of preparing the .sid file to be uploaded to AGOL as a tile layer so that it can be added to the web application?

I have ArcGIS 10.8, ArcCatalog 10.8, and QGIS 3.24 at my disposal. I am in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article posted on the ESRI Community website that ultimately answered this question.

[Publish a Tiled Service to ArcGIS Online](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-documents/publish-a-tiled-service-to-arcgis-online-w-o/ta-p/916035)

Comment: Can you summarize here in case the link breaks in the future?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).